# Solving ODEs via power series - what is wrong with my solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I need to solve the ODE $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-\frac 1 4 )y=0$.

The solution I should get is $y(x)=x^{\frac{-1}2}\sin x$, but using power series, I got all the coefficients are zero.

Here is my solution-

[image]

Comment: Did you make sure to check if this differential equation is ordinary?

Comment: @VarunIyer yes, there is only one variable... Or do you mean something else?

Comment: isn't this vessel's equation of order $1/2?$

Comment: @abel I didn't know aout Bessel's equation before, but a short google search shows you are right

Comment: @Whyka this differential equation isn't ordinary which is why your series method doesn't work. Look at my answer for further detail.

Comment: You need to use the [Method of Frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method).

Comment: @chappers I think you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This differential equation is ordinary, but the point $x = 0$ isn't a regular singular point.

You're calculating a series solution for this differential equation about the point $x = 0$, therefore $x_0 = 0$.

In order to check whether the differential equation is ordinary, substitute the point $x_0$ for the coefficient in $y''$. In this case, we have the coefficient is $x^2$.

If $p(x_0) \ne 0$, where $p(x)$ is the polynomial as the coefficient of the $y''$
 term, then the point is ordinary. Because we get that $p(0) = 0^2 = 0$, we have a singular point and therefore cannot use the method you described above to solve the differential equation.

Instead, consider using a Euler Equation.

Comment: Thank you!
I don't know the term "ordinary" you are using. By wikipedia, the term "ordinary" is used in contrast with the term partial differential equation which may be with respect to more than one independent variable.
But I think I understand what you are saying. However, this is a question in power series...

Comment: you don't mean ordinary; you intend to mean the $x = 0$ is a  regular singular point. the differential equation is ordinary.

Comment: @abel my mistake that is what I meant.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point Nonsingular points are called ordinary points.

Answer (score 1):

If there are two solutions $x^{-1/2}\sin(x)$ and $x^{-1/2}\cos(x)$ then the only solution of the form $\sum a_nx^n$ is $0$. Try $$y=x^{-1/2}\sum a_nx^n$$instead.

Comment: Oh, I see... How could I have known it without knowing the solution in advance?

Comment: Good question. Did they say you should use power series? The other answer explains how you could have known that $\sum a_nx^n$ won't work, which of course is not the same question...

Comment: @Whyka, look at the differential equation for large $x.$ it reduces to $y'' + y = 0$ whose solutions are $\sin x, \cos x.$

Comment: Yes, I do need to use power series. But they also asked me to solve it in a different way before, where I got the solution from... So they must have intended I use the known solution. So maybe your solution is what they meant

Comment: @abel Interesting...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Hi again. I used the Frobenius method, and by it there are two solution - $y_1=x^{0.5} \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$ and $y_2=cy_1(x)logx+x^{-0.5} \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k x^k$. Trying to use $y_1$, I got somewhere close but not to the solution I want $x^{-0.5} sinx$. What do you say- whould it make sense to try $y_2$ or do I have a mistake somewhere along the way with $y_1$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No idea, sorry.